# Shifting Polygon inside Polygon

Tags: algorithm

I'm having troubles figuring out an algorithm to solve the following problem:

[image]

I want the user to be able to snap the rectangle (Could be any type of polygon) to the 4 corners of the polygon such that it's as far inside the polygon as it can be.

What I'm trying so far:

1. Allow user to get the object.
2. Find the nearest vertice on the polygon to the rectangle.
3. Find the furthest vertice on the rectangle to the polygon's nearest vertice.
4. Use a plane to find the first intersection point with the furthest rectangle's point to the polygon's point.
5. Shift up or down using the corresponding x/y plane based on whether the furthest point is further in the x/y coordinate.
6. Keep repeating the steps above until everything is inside.

Comment: *"(Could be any type of polygon)"* That statement turns a trivial problem (rectangle in convex quadrilateral) into an (almost) impossible problem. [There are many types of polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon). So I think you need to refine your requirements a little more.

Comment: Maybe we can assume it's a simple rectangle for now I don't think many of the possible shapes that I'll need to account for will be much more difficult than a rectangle.

Comment: The solution to your example is two steps. 1) Determine which vertices of the rectangle touch the edges of the quadrilateral (the general case is two vertices touching two edges). 2) That leads to two equations where a point (x,y) needs to be on a line. The result is two equations in two variables, which can be solved algebraically.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to really understand the solution that you provided. I need the rectangles to be as close to each vertice in the polygon as possible.

Comment: See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You've described your solution, but not the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @user3386109 The problem was reasonably well described.  He wants to be able to pick a corner of the enclosing polygon and then position the smaller one so that it is as close as possible to that corner while still being inside of the enclosing one.

Comment: @btilly When you have to preface your answer with a conditional (*"as long as..."*), the problem was not well described.

Comment: @user3386109 That is a sign not of the question being unclear, but that I did not know a fully general solution.  So I described a solution to a special case that I hoped would be general enough.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but what btilly said above is what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as the enclosing polygon is convex, you can write this as a linear programming problem and then apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm to find the answer.  The smaller polygon you are putting inside can be as complicated as you want.

Your inequalities are all of the conditions to make sure that each vertex of the smaller polygon is inside of the larger.  You don't have to be clever here, there is no cost to extra inequalities that don't come into play.

The function to optimize is constructed as follows.  Look at the interior angle of the vertex you are trying to get close to.  Draw a coordinate system at that point with one axis pointing directly into the polygon (call that axis `y`) and the other at right angles to the first (call that axis `x`).  You want to minimize the `y` value of the nearest vertex on the polygon you are putting in.  (Just put the polygon you are putting in in the middle, and search for the nearest vertex.  Use that.

The solution that you find will be the one that puts the two vertices as close together as possible subject to the condition that the smaller polygon has to be inside of the larger.

Comment: Hi @btilly sorry I'm not able to fully understand the steps I need to take for this.
Are they somewhere along the lines of:

1. Place the smaller polygon in the center of the larger.
2. Find the nearest vertice on the smaller polygon to the vertice we are at.
3. Shift the small polygon to the vertice and rotate until we are full inside?

Comment: Did some more work and I have something working but it's pretty hacky.
1. Shift smaller polygon to middle of larger polygon.
2. Shift smaller polygon to user's closest vertice on larger polygon based on smaller polygon's closest vertice.
3. Use a loop to shift the polygon right/left or up/down until all vertices are inside. (This doesn't work we aren't in a normal x/y orientation)

Comment: @WonkaBear I did not realize that you could rotate.  I was saying put the smaller in the center of the larger.  Find the nearest vertex.  Write the conditions for the smaller to be inside as a series of linear equations.  Use the Simplex method to find a solution to that which puts the nearest vertex as close to the one to snap to as you can.